# Having virtual keyboard in another language while using physical keyboard in English on macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard

is it possible to have floating virtual keyboard in another language while using physical keyboard in English on macOS.
Thus I can write in English with my keyboard and use my trackpad to click on the virtual keyboard for the other language, in the same time.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Are we talking of a totally non-Western input or just 'some accents'?

Comment: What exactly is the "other language"?  I doubt what you suggest is possible, but there may well be other ways (e.g. custom keyboard layouts) of doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: Non-latin characters. Like Hebrew.

Comment: The goal is to find an easy way of writing in English then switching in Hebrew. A floating virtual keyboard in Hebrew associated with the physical keyboard in English should be a good solution.